# Can't get dual monitor to work on Ubunt 12.04 (ATI Radeon 2400HD)

Tags: radeon, monitor

I had Ubuntu 14.04 and tried various methods detailed online, but could not get dual monitors to work;  therefore I downgraded to 12.04.  Still having trouble.  Using the generic driver, when I go to the display settings, only one monitor is detected.   The "mirror" checkbox is grayed out and already unchecked, so I can't uncheck it as suggested in others' instructions.   Is it best to try installing the proprietary driver now?

Comment: You better go up to 15.04 instead of downgrading to 12.04 if you are having problems detecting your monitor. Try the live system first and see if it detects your monitor with and without the propietary drivers before you make a decision on what to install. Checking dmesg when connecting the monitor will also be useful information for us to help you.

Comment: can you describe *what methods* you tried?